# Running hurl invoke returns Transaction proposal was bad

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, convector, hurley

While invoking a Controller method with `hurl invoke`, the console returns:

```
[hurley] - Sending transaction...
2019-02-28T22:55:07.051Z - error: [Peer.js]: sendProposal - timed out after:30000
[hurley] - Transaction failed!
{ Error: Transaction proposal was bad
```

The parameters match in number and type.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, since the first two parameters were `:numbers`, I was sending them thru the console without double quotes. However, double quotes are still required, even if the parameter is a number

Eg:

```
hurl invoke mychaincode mychaincode_someMethod "87" "2" "Description"
```

"87" and "2" need to be sent with double quotes, even if they are number in the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
hurl invoke mychaincode mychaincode_someMethod "{\"id\":\"idata\",\"name\":\"namedata\",\"number\":\"123\", ....... "}"
```